# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Mathematics's [seventh moderator election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Asaf Karagila] [image: Aloizio Macedo]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [Mariano Suárez-Álvarez](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/274/mariano-su%C3%A1rez-%C3%81lvarez) who is stepping down as a moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5380598508027904/0).

Comment: Oh, wow. Mariano is stepping down? Talk about an end of an era! Thanks Mariano!

Comment: Congratulations to both of you.  I, for one, welcome our new overlords.

Comment: Congratulations to you both, and thanks to Mariano for his dedication!

Comment: Congratulations to both of you and many wishes for your new role here!

Comment: It is sad that in a few months two valuable people have stopped being moderators. My best wishes to them.

Comment: @user243301: On the positive side, Math has a very strong bench of moderator candidates. It's a real benefit that good moderators can take a break before they get burnt out.

Comment: Voted for both of you. Very excited for this new chapter for both of you, and MSE. Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats both! Your answers definitely clinched it for me! Here's to a bit of nourishing humour and enthusiasm to raise the spirits together with the other necessities :) the very best of  luck!

Comment: congratulations to both of you Asaf and Alosio...And a big thanks to Mariano...

Comment: Thank-you for volunteering guys. If at some point it feels like a thankless task, please take heart from remembering how sincerely grateful we all are even though we probably don't say so often enough.

Comment: Mariano, thanks so much for your service!

Comment: Again, it is sad that in a few months valuable people have stopped being moderators. My thought/belief is that this site MSE has problems that have to be solved.

Comment: Again, it is sad that in a few months valuable people have stopped being moderators. My thought/belief is that this site MSE has problems that have to be solved.

Comment: Hi, @user243301. I'm sorry you feel that way but it's hard to know how repeating your comment helps.

Answer (score 43):

Congratulations guys. It's awesome to see you working. Thanks to the outgoing moderator

Comment: How did this get a score of 17?

Comment: @TobyMak Why the negativity? I think 26 people agree with the answer. Don't you?